# How do you project the contents of a server that has been accessed remotely by a PC to a v screen which has a vga cable connected the server

Tags: windows-8

I have a PC and a monitoring screen on a wall .....a server in the server room is connected to the monitor using a vga cable.......i can remotely access the server through my PC but i want everyone in my section to be able to see what am seeing on my screen right on the monitor

Comment: If you were helped by a solution, as it appears you were by the VNC solution, it is likely a good idea to [accept it](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If it's connected via VGA, it should show up as a separate monitor.

You'll want to `Duplicate` what you see on your PC to the TV by doing the following from [Connect a second monitor or projector](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/how-connect-multiple-monitors)

> Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, and then tap Devices. (If
>   you're using a mouse, point to the lower-right corner of the screen,
>   move the mouse pointer up, and then click Devices.)
>
> Tap or click Project, and then select this option:
>
> Duplicate. You’ll see the same things on both screens.

A description for completeness of the other options follows:

> PC screen only. You’ll see everything on your PC. (When you're
>   connected to a wireless projector, this option changes to Disconnect.)
>
> Extend. You'll see everything spread over both screens, and you can
>   drag and move items between the two.
>
> Second screen only. You’ll see everything on the connected screen.
>   Your other screen will be blank.

Comment: Thank you Johnny Vegas........ VNC worked perfectly........and thanks also ssnobody for you contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Setup Tightvnc on the server (www.tightvnc.com) and the same on your computer (client only) - Make sure you allow port 5900 incoming on the firewall. Get the IP address of the server and on your computer, connect to the server with the vnc client.

The servers mouse and keyboard will be controlled by your computer which in turn will be viewed on the monitor.

Make sure a VNC password is set on the server - You will be prompted during install and make sure the vnc software is uninstalled from the server after you have finished.